# How to add values per character in c#?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and do not know how to explain this but I wanted to know if it was possible to add a charge for every character that is entered into a text box.

For example if the customer was to enter "HELLO HI" they should be charged £5 with a additional cost of £1 per letter or number this £1 charge should also apply for any spaces entered.

Sorry if I have not explained this properly but this is the best way I can.

Thank you

Comment: please add your code!!!!!

Comment: I don't have a code which is why I am asking. Sorry

Comment: or provide several more examples

Comment: just count the number of characters and determine the charge? Attach to the onChange event if you need it in real time.

Comment: Okay... If the customer entered "Happy Birthday" there should be a £5 charge with £1 per character so the overall total should be £19 as they are being charges £1 for the spaces as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int amount;
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            amount = 5;
            amount = amount + textBox1.Text.Length;            
            label1.Text = amount.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it pretty much looks like this, I guess:

```
string str =  "Happy Birthday";
int price = str.Length + 5;
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this. It does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Find the length of entered string in textbox using  TextboxID.text.Length and add your fix charge that 5 , as ALEX explain you. 
please see alex's answer.